# What is this "bird like" plane?

Tags: aircraft, identify-this

So, I'm sat at London Heathrow's Terminal 5, looking out the window while waiting for a flight, and a plane that looks to me to most intents and purposes like a bird just rolled past...

[image: A bird-like plane at Heathrow's T5]

(Hopefully you can make it out, despite the photo being taken into the sun)

I'm guessing that someone wouldn't just paint their plane in gold bird feathers for fun, and there's a reason behind it. Anyone know what the plane is, and what the story is behind the gold bird feathers paint job?

Comment: It's the plane in the foreground. Zooming in or cropping doesn't really help, given the light, and I can't get a better shot form here. Will try to get one later, assuming it doesn't move!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'd be more confident if you'd got the tail in the picture, but is it this:

[image]

[An article in the Daily Mail](http://travelchatter.dailymail.co.uk/2012/04/british-airways-and-tracey-emin-unveil-first-specially-designed-olympic-plane.html) says it's a British Airways Olympic themed plane.

> British Airways has unveiled its first of nine Olympic-themed jets, revealing a striking white plane painted with gold feathers that will go into service [03 April 2012].
>   The Airbus A319 has been decorated to resemble a giant gold dove by designer Pascal Anson who was mentored by Tracey Emin. She praised the design for bringing back the excitement of travel

Comment: I can now see the tail out of the window, yup it's that one!

Comment: cool! I love seeing the "themed" planes in action